# What is the grammar behind the expression 行きそう、行きそう?

Tags: untagged

I heard a guy on the street calling his girlfriend from a distance: ありさ、行きそう、行きそう! and she hurried up to him. From the context, it seems like it means "Let's go, let's go". Somehow google translate knows that "行きそう、行きそう" means "Let's go, let's go", and "行きそう" means "Likely to go". Obviously repetition of the phrase changing the meaning. What is the grammar of this construction? Is it a typical usage of 連用形+そう? I know the textbook explanation of "appearance of doing/being something", but it seems like this repetitive usage does not fit that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please make sure you have not misheard 行くぞ, 行くよ, or something.

If you're 100% sure that the the guy was saying 行きそう, it never means "Let's go", no matter how many times it's said. Don't trust Google Translate.

行きそう just means "It's going", or move verbosely, "It looks like it's about to go". Probably he was was watching something that can be described as 行く, such as a rocket launch.

Answer (score 5):

I think you misheard the person saying 行くぞ、行くぞ, which is a brusque way of saying what you guessed.